# JBAS018733 : Failed to process phase PARSE of subdeployment

Tags: java, jboss, jboss-eap-6

Hi I'm using JBOSS EAP 6.4 and JDK java version "1.7.0_79".The deployments are failing due to below error. I tried various solutions available on the web. Can anyone shed some light on this. Any help is much appreciated.

```
  16:59:51,595 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015973: Starting subdeployment (runtime-name: "Project-WAR.war")
  16:59:51,596 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015973: Starting subdeployment (runtime-name: "Project.jar")
  16:59:52,145 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC000001: Failed to start service         jboss.deployment.subunit."Project-EAR.ear"."Project-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar".PARSE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."Project-EAR.ear"."Project-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar".PARSE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase PARSE of subdeployment "Project-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar" of deployment "Project-EAR.ear"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:166) [jboss-as-server-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1980) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1913) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
  Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceNotFoundException: Service service jboss.ejb.default-resource-adapter-name-service not found
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceContainerImpl.getRequiredService(ServiceContainerImpl.java:625) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.getDefaultResourceAdapterName(MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.java:275)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.processMessageBeans(MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.java:155)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.processAnnotations(MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.java:82)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.AnnotatedEJBComponentDescriptionDeploymentUnitProcessor.processAnnotations(AnnotatedEJBComponentDescriptionDeploymentUnitProcessor.java:58)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.AbstractDeploymentUnitProcessor.deploy(AbstractDeploymentUnitProcessor.java:81)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:159) [jboss-as-server-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    ... 5 more

  16:59:52,228 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014612: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "Project-EAR.ear")]) - failure description: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.subunit.\"Project-EAR.ear\".\"Project-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar\".PARSE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit.\"Project-EAR.ear\".\"Project-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar\".PARSE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase PARSE of subdeployment \"Project-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar\" of deployment \"Project-EAR.ear\"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

are you using jms in your project? If so, the problem could be that you are not installing the messaging subsytem.. try starting your eap with standalone-full profile (which includes `<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging:1.1">`)

Comment: We are using apache activemq for messaging. I have started the eap with standalone-full-ha.xml which resulted in the above error

Comment: eap 6.4 comes with hornetq as jms implementation.. are you trying to deploy activemq inside jboss?

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this issue on jboss-eap-6.1

> "JBAS018733 : Failed to process phase PARSE..."

Cause-found duplicate JARs were in the ...WAR/WEB-INF/lib/1.2.X.jar

Solution:

1. removed older version of the two `..<APPNAME>.WAR/WEB-INF/lib/<APPNAME>1.2.X.jar`
2. cleanout `../tmp/vfs`
3. cleanout `../tmp/work/jboss.web/default-host/<APPNAME>Webservice`
4. restart Jboss